# Adding or subtracting value depending on value of two columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table where I already implemented some query to create two columns where one column is equal to zero while the other is not. It can look like this

```
...| a | b |
   | 1 | 0 |
   | 0 | 1 |
   | 1 | 0 |
   | 1 | 0 |
   | 1 | 0 |
   | 0 | 2 |
   | 0 | 1 |
   | 1 | 0 |
```

No I am trying to find a sql statement that adds up column a if it's not 0 and also subtracts the value b from it. So my result should look like this

```
   | a | b | result |
   | 1 | 0 |   1    |
   | 0 | 1 |   0    |
   | 1 | 0 |   1    |
   | 1 | 0 |   2    |
   | 1 | 0 |   3    |
   | 0 | 2 |   1    |
   | 0 | 1 |   0    |
   | 1 | 0 |   1    |
```

I tried a lot with sum, count, case when, etc. but as sql noob I am not sure if those are the right functions for this problem.

Comment: mysql or sqlite - they are not the same. Also what mysql version are you on?

Comment: You want what is called a "running total". Be aware that table data is an unordered data set by definition. Is there any column that determines the order of the rows, like a date, an ID, some sortkey?

Comment: yes, I have a column with Timestamps that defines the order. But I don't know the sql version. I use a sqlite db to run queries on out of a C++ program. And for creation of the queries I use DB Browser for sqlite where I can open my db in and run statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a running total. This is usually achieved with the window function `SUM OVER`. You have mistakenly tagged two different DBMS, MySQL and SQLite, but both support this standard SQL functionality - unless you are using an old version.

Table data is an unordered set of data, so you need something that determines the order. I am assuming some sortkey in below query:

```
select sortkey, a, b, sum(a - b) over (order by sortkey) as total
from ( <your query> ) q
order by sortkey;
```